# In Rails 6, where do I place moneky patch code so that it gets run before the Gem code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6, monkeypatching, gemfile

I’m using Ruby 3.0.2 and Rails 6.1.4.4.  I have installed a gem, octoshark v 0.3.0, that doesn’t play well with Ruby 3.  The gem file is

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2@cfs-web/gems/octoshark-0.3.0/lib/octoshark/active_record_extensions.rb
```

And the specific line is line 5 in its ConnectionHandler.establish_connection method.  I want to monkey-patch this method but putting my code into a file, lib/ext/octoshark/active_record_extensions.rb, and then loading it in config/initializers/ext.rb with

```
Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('lib/ext/**/*.rb')).sort.each do |filename|
  require filename
end
```

But when I start my server, it appears my Octoshark gem code is getting called before the monkey patch code.  (I proved this by putting a statement in the “ext.rb” file that would intentionally raise an error). What’s the right way to monkey patch this file?

**Edit**: Per the suggestion given, I created a file, lib/core_extensions/octoshark/connection_handler.rb, with this

```
module CoreExtensions
  module Octoshark
    module ConnectionHandler
      def establish_connection(config, **parameters)
        Octoshark::ConnectionPoolsManager.reset_connection_managers!
        super(config, **parameters)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this related to [issue #39](https://github.com/dalibor/octoshark/issues/39)? Might be easier to fork the gem, send in a pull request with a fix, and put your patched version in your `Gemfile` while the gem gets officially sorted out.

Comment: Definitely seems to be the same issue.  Is it possible to monkey patch this without waiting for a new Gem to be released?

Comment: In the past I've forked the gem at Github, fixed my fork, and then referenced my version of the gem in my Gemfile (see https://bundler.io/guides/git.html). If you have a fix already, this approach is clean, easy, and easy to undo when the official version gets fixed.

Comment: on another note, `OctoShark` is not needed in rails 6 for multi-database connections, and for connection pools you'll want to use a database-specific gem.

Comment: Hate to bring this right down to the wire, but can you point me to what would be the replacement in Rails 6 for Octoshark if I'm using MySql 5.7?  I think that would effectively answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to make a `monkeypatch` folder inside your initializers:

```
$ mkdir config/initializers/monkeypatch
```

Then you can separate by file:

```
$ touch config/initializers/monkeypatch/string.rb
$ touch config/initializers/monkeypatch/array.rb
$ touch config/initializers/monkeypatch/hash.rb
```

Comment: Is it enough to put a file in "config/initializers"?  Does the file just get automatically loaded?  In my question, I included the path to my patch (config/initializers/ext.rb) as well as the contents of taht file and this isn't working.

Comment: 100% of initializers are loaded at boot. This is where config files go for all gems, you can check by doing a `raise("LOADING MONKEYPATCH")` at the top of the file. make sure you're spelling it all correctly, the folder of initializers comes with other files

Comment: @Dave i'm not making any guarantees about your code, but the code inside the `initializers` folder are being ran at boot and used to configure gems.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend looking up the exact error you have. Most likely other gems have encountered the same issue and there could be a fix there.

Generally speaking though, you would just add an initializer for it and put your patch there. Though if it breaks before it is even initialized then that would be interesting and you could probably put it near the top of the `config/application.rb` (you might need to experiment with exactly where).